# Rails wizard like form using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to build a wizard like multi-step input form for my model.

I want to stick to rest practices as long as possible.

The individual steps in the wizard don't have much inter-dependency so to avoid the round trip to the server, I want to store the whole data on client side using JQueryUI tabs or similar.

I have following question.

1. Is there any better way this could be achieved ?
2. Can anyone point me to any example or documentation regarding the use JQueryUI-tabs and rails together ?

regards.

Comment: If there isn't inter-dependency it's not a wizard.

Comment: The fields in all the steps belong to the same model, but not inter-depended in terms of validations e.i. I don't want to validate fields on step3 based on some values of fields in step2.

Comment: Possible duplicate, or related otherwise: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603464/how-to-create-wizard-forms-in-ruby-on-rails Nice answers over there

Comment: Chubas, I have read the post. What I am interested is a jQueryUI tabs solutions not a rails plugin

Answer (score -1):

Try http://github.com/CodeOfficer/jquery-ui-rails-helpers which has a JQueryUI tab helper.